# Recommended JavaScript Array of Objects Size

Tags: javascript, dom, multidimensional-array

The page I am building should display a list of items. Let's say these are products for sale, as an example. One item will have a short title (50-200 characters), price, and some other brief information. There may normally be 200 items per category. However, rarely there are 1000 and maximum 5000 items (very rarely).

I was thinking about preloading all items into JavaScript array of objects to make pagination smooth and product filter. Based on user selection on the filter or page number DOM would easily redraw the results for display. This would work fine for 200 items I am sure. But what about 5000? Will it slow down browsers if you loop through so many items?

Should I preload everything once and display items dynamically (never make another call to the server) or is it still the best way to load pieces of data from the server per user selection? Thanks.

Comment: To know which is more performant, you'll have to test. I'd just suggest only loading what the user needs when it's needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have to worry. Your only worry would be getting the data over the line (to the user's browser). `5000 × 200 = 1000000` bytes, so it would be a little over 1MB.

JavaScript performance is probably not an issue. In my test (on a moderately old laptop in Chrome 16) it took only **`1ms`** to create 5000 mock objects and iterate over them, concatenating the descriptions and adding up the prices. Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/PPvG/G3UDH/

Bandwidth-wise, loading everything up front is probably better if the connection between client and server is high-bandwidth and high-latency. If the connection is low-bandwidth and low-latency, loading in parts might result in a better user experience. So which approach is best depends on the situation.